# Map combobox options for translation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have a bunch of state names in my data model that I want to map to different keys for translation, e.g.

- Open -> state_open
- New -> state_new
- Wait for approval -> state_wait_for_approval

Currently my combo box is populated this way:

```
<select class="form-control select" id="client"
  ng-model="statusType"
  ng-change="setStatusType(statusType)"
  ng-options="statusType.name for statusType in statusTypes track by statusType.id">
  <option value="">-</option>
</select>
```

I have read that I can implement translation by doing this:

```
  ng-options="statusType.name | translate for statusType in statusTypes track by statusType.id">
```

However, this will assume that my translation keys are equal to the state names. I would rather like to map my state names to the translation keys mentioned above.

How can I implement this mechanism in Angular? I probably need some sort of custom directive (?). I'm new to Angular, so all hints are welcome.

I'm thinking of something like:

```
mapStateToTranslationKey(statusType.name) -> return "status_" + toLowerCase(replaceSpacesWithUnderscores(statusType.name))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself. Basically, I had to add this function to my controller:

```
$scope.mapStateToTranslationKey = function(stateName) {
   return "state_" + stateName.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('_');
};
```

This function will convert the state name to lower case, replace all spaces by underscores and finally prepend the string `state_`. Ultimately, it returns a key, I can use for translation with **angular-translate**.

In the view, I now have to call my function first and then use the `translate` keyword after the pipe symbol. This way the translation key will be used instead of the actual state name.

```
<select class="form-control select" id="client"
   ng-model="statusType"
   ng-change="setStatusType(statusType)"
   ng-options="mapStateToTranslationKey(statusType.name) | translate for statusType in statusTypes track by statusType.id">
  <option value="">-</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

From this link, https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide, my assumption is that Angular does not translate anything, you would need to write the code that tells Angular that "hey, when you see this word, translate it into this word."

You may be expecting functionality that does not exist. I would think that in the translate function you would need to write in Javascript, using the Angular function ".translations()" you would need to explicitly translate both the name and the key. And, return the single value you are expecting.

Comment: There is an Angular extension called **angular-translate**, which I am using: https://angular-translate.github.io